Re-fomulate bitwise boolean expressions between register bits in terms of register values
Suppose we have two e.g. 32-bit input registers and one equally wide output register, with boolean functions linking individual bits of these registers. Is there a method to express these bitwise connections with functions that treat the registers as 32-bit values?
I've considered the template recognition for different well known structures like adders, multipliers etc. along with the Z3 solver.
Maybe someone has a better idea?

You can define a custom function. Is that what you want to do?
https://play.formal-methods.net/?check=SMT&p=chatty-thing-stick-spore

The template method you're alluding to (i.e., "pattern recognition" of certain structures like adders/multipliers) is the best way to go, using z3 to ensure your "guess" is correct.
Note that this is in general a very difficult problem. Not only the "word-equivalent" is not uniquely defined, the problem ends up being very similar to graph isomorphism/clique identification; and thus it is computationally expensive. (Note that "checking" if your guess is correct is--in general--much easier.)
